# How do I make a call from Excel 2016 to a REST API

Tags: excel, vba, rest

I am experminenting for the first time with some REST API calls from Excel 2016, I have the following code which includes header elements from a working call out of PostMan however when I attempt to implement from VBA I get the error "Type Mismatch".  As I an not familiar with REST API call functionality from Excel, I can't identify what the problem is.  Can someone please assist.

```vb
    With objRequest
        .Open "GET", strUrl, blnAsync
        .SetRequestHeader _
            "Authorization", "Bearer <...>" _
             & "Content-Type", "Content-Type" = "application/json; charset=utf-8" _
             & "Cache-Control" = "no-cache" _
             & "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" = "*" _
             & "Access-Control-Allow-Methods" = "GET" _
             & "X-AspNet-Version" = "4.0.30319" _
             & Expires = "-1" _
             & Pragma = "no-cache" _
             & "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" = "authorization,Access-Control-Allow-Origin,Content-Type,SOAPAction" _
             & "Content-Type" = "application/json; charset=utf-8" _
             & "X-Powered-By" = "ASP.NET" _
             & "Transfer-Encoding" = "chunked" _
             & Connection = "keep-alive"
        .Send
        'spin wheels whilst waiting for response
        While objRequest.readyState <> 4
            DoEvents
        Wend
        strResponse = .ResponseText
    End With
```

New function for generating security token with confidential elements omitted:

```vb
Public Function GetToken() As String

    Dim objRequest As Object
    Dim strUrl As String
    Dim blnAsync As Boolean
    Dim strResponse As String
    
    Set objRequest = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    strUrl = "https://<...>"
    blnAsync = True

    With objRequest
        .Open "GET", strUrl, blnAsync
        .SetRequestHeader "Authorization", "Basic=<...>"
        .SetRequestHeader "Content-Type", "Content-Type" = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        .SetRequestHeader "X-Frame-Options", "DENY"
        .SetRequestHeader "Cache-Control", "no-store"
        '.SetRequestHeader "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"
        .SetRequestHeader "Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST"
        .SetRequestHeader "X-Content-Type-Options", "nosniff"
        .SetRequestHeader "Pragma", "no-cache"
        .SetRequestHeader "X-XSS-Protection", "1; mode=block"
        .SetRequestHeader "Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "authorization,Access-Control-Allow-Origin,Content-Type,SOAPAction"
        .SetRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8"
        .SetRequestHeader "X-Powered-By", "ASP.NET"
        .SetRequestHeader "Transfer-Encoding", "chunked"
        .SetRequestHeader "Connection", "keep-alive"
        .Send
        'spin wheels whilst waiting for response
        While objRequest.readyState <> 4
            DoEvents
        Wend
        strResponse = .ResponseText
    End With
    
    Debug.Print strResponse

End Function
```

The GetToken function responds with the error:

```
 <faultstring>org.apache.synapse.SynapseException: 
    Error occured in the mediation of the class mediator</faultstring>
```

Latest iteration of code 03/08/2021:

Public Function GetToken(ByVal bas As String) As String

```
Dim objrequest As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
Dim strUrl As String
Dim blnAsync As Boolean
Dim strResponse As String

Set objrequest = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
strUrl = "https://<...>/token"
blnAsync = False


'C# Equivalent to PostMan Entry.
'var client = new RestClient("https://<...>/token");
'client.Timeout = -1;
'var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
'request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Basic <...>");
'request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
'request.AddParameter("grant_type", "client_credentials");
'request.AddParameter("Content_Type", "application%2Fx-www-form-urlencoded");
'IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
'Console.WriteLine(response.Content);

With objrequest
    .Open "POST", strUrl, False
    .setRequestHeader "Authorization", "Basic " & EncodeBase64(bas)
    .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    .setRequestHeader "Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST"
    .send "grant_type=client_credentials&content_type=application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    'spin wheels whilst waiting for response
    While objrequest.readyState <> 4
        DoEvents
    Wend
    strResponse = .ResponseText
End With

Debug.Print strResponse
```

End Function

Kind Regards
Paul.

Comment: You make multiple `.setRequestHeader` method for each header, not concatenate them as 1 string

Comment: Raymond, thefunction now works, with security token acquired from PostMan.  My next port of call was to try and generate the token from within Excel using a function GetToken, unfortunately this does not appear to work.  Have updated the original post with the new code and the error that I am now getting.

Comment: Without the URL/documentation of what you are trying to call, it's hard to advise you. However, I don't think you need that many headers in the first place (at least from my limited experience of calling API!). Most likely just the `Authorization` header is good enough so delete the rest of the headers and try again (and consult the API documentation!)

Comment: If I'm not wrong, you should set `blnAsync` to False unless you are trying to do async request.

Comment: You have two instances of the `Content-Type` header. That can't be right. Especially this one `.SetRequestHeader "Content-Type", "Content-Type" = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"` is definitely wrong. If anything, It should be `.SetRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"`. Apart from that you need to figure out which is the `Content_Type` you need. Is it `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` or is it `application/json; charset=utf-8`?

Comment: Most probably the only headers that are essential to your request should be `Authorization` and `Content-Type`. Chances are the other ones are obsolete.

Comment: It looks like you're confusing *Response* headers with *Request* headers.  They serve different purposes.  Request headers tell the server about what you're requesting and how you'd like to receive the response.  Response headers contain information about the response (plus cookies etc)

Comment: Ok guys, have made some progress, however I am now receiving the error: {"error_description":"A valid OAuth client could not be found for client_id: <...>","error":"invalid_client"}. The added code contains the C# equivalent of the PostMan entry which is working.  . I have used <...> to denote confidential content

Comment: You are calling the `EncodeBase64()` function to get the encoded string. You are passing a parameter named `bas`. Is this parameter defined somewhere in your code? Do you assign a value to this parameter? Have you tried `debug.print EncodeBase64(bas)` to see if you get the desired result?